# c++ sprintf's format how to transfer a var

Tags: c++

I want to tansfer a var to sprintf's format, but how to!

```
char s[100];
int d = 4;
sprintf(s, "%4s", "abc"); // i want the var 'd' replace '4', but how.
cout << s;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an asterisk as precision, and place the wanted expression before the format argument:

```
sprintf(s, "%*s", d, "abc");
```

Comment: +1 for the asterisk.  Better than constructing the format string first.

Comment: @facebook-100001174928894 Just add them as usual: `sprintf(s, "%*s %d", d, "abc", 123);`